# Dynamically generated ListView doesn't populate based on its model

Tags: qt, user-interface, dynamic, combobox, qml

I'm creating a combobox manually by sending a string to Qt.createQmlObject like so:

```
var newQML = "ComboBox {\n";
newQML += "  model: ListModel {\n"
newQML += "    ListElement {\n"
newQML += "      name: \"One\"\n"
newQML += "    }\n"
newQML += "  }\n"
newQML += "}\n"

var cBox = Qt.createQmlObject(newQML)
```

However, the combo box doesn't populate entries from its ListModel (it just stays empty.) I also tried creating a ListModel in the component that this is being instantiated into, gave it an id, and then tried referencing that id in my code like so:

```
var newQML = "ComboBox {\n";
newQML += "  model: sampleModel\n"
newQML += "}\n"

var cBox = Qt.createQmlObject(newQML)
```

However, that doesn't work either. Please let me know the correct way to instantiate and populate a ComboBox dynamically in QML.

Answer (score 0):

First, import statements should be included in the string that passed to `Qt.createQmlObject`. Since you are using `ListModel` and `ComboBox`, you should import `QtQuick` and `QtQuick.Controls` in `newQML`:

```
var newQML = "import QtQuick 2.0; \n";
newQML += "import QtQuick.Controls 2.0\n";
newQML += "ComboBox {\n";
newQML += "  model: ListModel {\n"
newQML += "    ListElement {\n"
newQML += "      name: \"One\"\n"
newQML += "    }\n"
newQML += "  }\n"
newQML += "}\n"
```

Next, you need to pass a parent item to `Qt.createQmlObject` to specify where to draw the combo box. For example, if you what to put the combo box in `mainItem`, then pass both `newQML` and `mainItem` to `Qt.createQmlObject`:

```
Item {
    id: mainItem
    width: 200; height: 200

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: {
            var newQML = "import QtQuick 2.0; \n";
            newQML += "import QtQuick.Controls 2.0\n";
            //...

            var cBox = Qt.createQmlObject(newQML, mainItem);
        }
    }
}
```

---

However, if you are using combo box from `QtQuick.Controls 1.x`, the above method is not working and the program gives you an empty combo box instead (tested in Qt 5.8 MSVC 2015). A simple workaround is to assign the model after the object is created:

```
var newQML = "import QtQuick 2.7; \n";
newQML += "import QtQuick.Controls 1.4\n";
newQML += "ComboBox {\n";
newQML += "}\n"

var cBox = Qt.createQmlObject(newQML, mainItem)
cBox.model = sampleModel;
```

But I think it's better to use `QtQuick.Controls 2` or `Qt.createComponent` instead.